# Create object generics class

Tags: c#, .net, oop, generics

I came across a question recently and I have not worked much on that in my past. I have a class named `ObjectCreator` with a method `Create`.

```
public static class ObjectCreator
{
    // Create method
}
```

I should be able to call the `Create` method in the following ways.

```
var obj1 = ObjectCreator.Create<Employee>();
var obj2 = ObjectCreator.Create<Client>();
var obj3 = ObjectCreator.Create<Company>();
```

and so on for any other type. Now how to implement the `Create` method here? Remember Create method does not accept any parameters here. Can anyone help me to get a work around?

Comment: Does all these classes (Employee, Client etc) have public parameterless constructor? Do you provide some data to instantiated objects?

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy They do not have to have public parameterless constructor. But I agree on that more info provided would be sweet.

Comment: This is pretty much similar to IOC container use case where you simply request object from the container, which then provides you with the object as per the registration contracts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
public static class ObjectCreator
{
    public static T Create<T>() where T : new()
    {
        return new T();
    }
}
```

I added the `T: new()` constraint (which forces the type `T` to have the default constructor) and the return statement just to illustrate one possible use case.

Comment: Are you sure that is what OP needs (see my comment to question)?

Comment: Also what does *constraint is optional* means? Without this constraint you cant return `new T()`

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy That's a good point, I just added the constraint and the return statement to make it *compilable* (is that a word?). I think the question was only about the signature though.. was it not?

Comment: Actually its not clear :) Thats why I asked OP about details. Maybe your solution would be what OP needs, don't know yet

Comment: If OP needs only `ObjectCreator` to be able to instantiate objects (meaning you can create a new `Employee` or `Client` only by using `ObjectCreator`), then precompiled lambdas are a good go. But still info on his usage intentions is missing.

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy That's true, I'll update my answer as needed when more info is provided

Comment: @dcastro: Thanks for the answer. Its giving compile time error on returning. Using `Activator.CreateInstance` works fine. However what if I dont have parameterless constructor?

Comment: @Sandy What does the compile error say? It compiles fine for me. (also, i just noticed you had an extra `()` on your code, i've removed it).

Comment: @Sandy So you're gonna create any of those classes in a generic way.. Did you have any strategy in mind?

Comment: @dcastro: Now it compiles, sorry my folly. And regarding strategy, well this was a question asked to me by a manager in casual chat so I think it not a real time implementation problem. It was just to test my knowledge I guess. And yeah any class can be instantiated. A request, can you guide me where can I really read some stuff about this kind in .net? I mean what should I search in google to do this?? Help is and will be appreciated. Thanks :)

Comment: @Sandy I asked because, if you're gonna go with generics, there must be an uniform way of handling all allowed types :) Just search for generics in c#. When you have a good grasp, learn about [Constraints on Type Parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx), and then take a look at the [Covariance and Contravariance FAQ](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2010/02/16/covariance-and-contravariance-faq.aspx). These are good tools for your toolbox.

Answer (score 2):

We already have [Activator.CreateInstance Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0hcyx2kd%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)  which requires (not forces) a parameterless public constructor. If no suitable constructor found it throws an exception at runtime. Since dcastor's answer forces a compile time error it seems better.

```
var obj1 = Activator.CreateInstance<Employee>();
var obj2 = Activator.CreateInstance<Client>();
var obj3 = Activator.CreateInstance<Company>();
```